# Why my NSColor class NSConcreteData?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

In the Data Model I've defined color as a transformable attribute and assigned ColorTransformer to it. It works, with help of the same transformer I can bind it to ColorPicker, save and open document.
[image: Screenshot from data model]
But when I try to access it from code:

```
NSColor * color = corner.color;
NSLog(@"Corner Color = %@\n%@", color, color.class);
```

I've got object of NSMutableConcreteData:

```
bezierMesh[22164:730708] Corner Color = <040b7374 7265616d 74797065 6481e803 84014084 8484074e 53436f6c 6f720084 84084e53 4f626a65 63740085 84016301 84046666 66660183 6eb7613d 8357703e 3e8352b8 1e3f86>
NSConcreteMutableData
```

Modifying getter and setter doesn't help:

```
- (NSColor *)color {

    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"color"];
    NSData *colorData = [self primitiveValueForKey:@"color"];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"color"];
    if (colorData == nil) {
        return nil;
    }


   NSColor * color = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:colorData];
   return color;
   }

- (void)setColor:(NSColor *)color {
    NSLog(@" -------------- > Setting color %@", color);
     NSData * theData=[NSArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:color];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"color"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:theData forKey:@"color"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"color"];
}
```

It causes an error:

```
[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: non-keyed archive cannot be decoded by NSKeyedUnarchiver
```

How to get color NSColor?

Comment: Is this an `NSValueTransformer` subclass we are talking about here?  If so then that's not how you'd use it from code.

Comment: BMColorTransformer is a subclass of NSTransformer. But maybe there is proper question: how to use NSTransformer subclass in code?

Comment: NSValueTransformer of course

Answer (score 1):

Here's an `NSString` <-> `NSColor` transformer I wrote a while back, which is designed to store colours using the RGB values within `NSUserDefaults` as I didn't like the default use of `NSData` objects:

StringColourTransformer.h:

```
@interface StringColourTransformer : NSValueTransformer

+ (NSString *)toString:(NSColor *)value;
+ (NSColor *)fromString:(NSString *)value;

@end
```

StringColourTransformer.m:

```
#import "StringColourTransformer.h"

@implementation StringColourTransformer

+ (NSString *)toString:(NSColor *)value {
    StringColourTransformer *transformer = [[StringColourTransformer alloc] init];
    NSString *str = [transformer reverseTransformedValue:value];
    return str;
}

+ (NSColor *)fromString:(NSString *)value {
    StringColourTransformer *transformer = [[StringColourTransformer alloc] init];
    NSColor *color = (NSColor *)[transformer transformedValue:value];
    return color;
}

+ (Class)transformedValueClass {
    return [NSColor class];
}

+ (BOOL)allowReverseTransformation {
    return YES;
}

- (id)transformedValue:(id)value {
    CGFloat r = 0.0, g = 0.0, b = 0.0, a = 1.0;

    // Only NSString classes are reverse-transformed
    if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        NSString *stringValue = (NSString *)value;
        sscanf([stringValue UTF8String],
#ifdef __x86_64
               "%lf %lf %lf %lf",
#else
               "%f %f %f %f",
#endif
               &r, &g, &b, &a);
    }

    return [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:a];
}

- (id)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value {
    CGFloat r = 0.0, g = 0.0, b = 0.0, a = 1.0;

    // Only NSColor classes are transformed
    if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSColor class]]) {
        NSColor *colourValue = (NSColor *)value;
        NSColor *converted = [colourValue colorUsingColorSpaceName:@"NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace"];
        [converted getRed:&r green:&g blue:&b alpha:&a];
    }

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f %.3f %.3f %.3f", r, g, b, a];
}

@end
```

As you can see I've provided a couple of class methods to make using it from code easier (`toString` and `fromString`).

It needs to be registered early in the app lifecycle so that it can be used to transform values within IB (this is called from a singleton where `_stringColourTransformer` is an instance variable):

```
_stringColourTransformer = [[StringColourTransformer alloc] init];
[NSValueTransformer setValueTransformer:_stringColourTransformer
                                forName:@"StringColourTransformer"];
```

and conversion is as simple as:

```
NSColor *colour = [StringColourTransformer fromString:@"1.0 1.0 0.0 1.0"];
```

Note: looking at the code now I would probably use `[NSValueTranformer valueTransformerForName:]` in the `toString`/`fromString` methods, rather than creating a new instance each time.  It's probably less expensive.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is about how to store UIColor (or NSColor on OS X) object in Core Data ...: NSValueTransformer is not necessary. Above entry "Name" in core data modeler must be empty (now there is:"BMColorTransformer").

The Entity ("MyData") interface (use NSColor accordingly with OS X) then looks like so in code:

```
@interface MyData : NSManagedObject

// other attributes ...
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIColor * color;

@end
```

and implementation ...

```
@implementation MyData

// other attributes ...
@dynamic color;

@end
```

But if you don't want UIColor (or NSColor) stored as NSData - which results in BLOB format in a Sqlite database - you need to write an NSValueTransformer like that one @trojanfoe posted. He says "I didn't like the default use of NSData" - i guess he preferred a readable format and not binary format (??).

Comment: So simple. 
BTW. My BTColorTransformer had -(NSColor *)... instead of +(Color *)...
Now works!